# Commands to export latex file

Tags: macros, lyx

I would like to create a trigger to export Latex file on the tool bar to replace Update trigger. Anyone knows the commands behind this Export>LaTeX(XeTeX)？Or where could I find the command?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Tools > Preferences ... FIle Handling ... > Converters

Comment: @KJO, well, actually the posted answer gives how to convert to pdf in command line, what I need is how to convert to LaTeX file in command line.